# Find least significant digit in a double in Python

Tags: python, precision, rounding-error

I have a lot of financial data stored as floating point doubles and I'm trying to find the least significant digit so that I can convert the data to integers with exponent.

All the data is finite, e.g. 1234.23 or 0.0001234 but because it's stored in doubles it can be 123.23000000001 or 0.00012339999999 etc

Is there an easy or proper approach to this or will I just have to botch it?

Comment: I don't think the problem is well defined tbh, because there can be multiple numbers which would end up to the same doubles, so information has already been lost..  financial data should never be stored in floating point in the first place.

Comment: In that case avoid floating point. Use [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options,

Firstly and most preferably, use the stdlib `Decimal`, not builtin `float`

This fixes most errors related to floats but not the infamous `0.1 + 0.2 = 0.3...4`

```py
from decimal import Demical

print(0.1 + 0.2)  # 0.30000000000000004
print(Decimal(0.1) + Decimal(0.2))  # 0.3000000000000000166533453694
```

An alternative option if that isn't possible, is setting a tolerance for number of repeated digits after the decimal point.

For example:

```py
import re

repeated_digit_tolerance = 8  # Change to an appropriate value for your dataset
repeated_digit_pattern = re.compile(r"(.)\1{2,}")

def longest_repeated_digit_re(s: str):
    match = repeated_digit_pattern.search(s)

    string = match.string
    span = match.span()
    substr_len = span[1] - span[0]

    return substr_len, string

def fix_rounding(num: float) -> float:
    num_str = str(num)
    pre_dp = num_str[:num_str.index(".")]
    post_dp = num_str[num_str.index(".") + 1:]

    repetition_length, string = longest_repeated_digit_re(post_dp)

    if repetition_length > repeated_digit_tolerance:
        shortened_string = string[:repeated_digit_tolerance-1]

    return float(".".join([pre_dp, shortened_string]))

print(0.1 + 0.2) # 0.30000000000000004
print(0.2 + 0.4) # 0.6000000000000001

print(fix_rounding(0.1 + 0.2))  # 0.3
print(fix_rounding(0.2 + 0.4))  # 0.6
```

It's perfectly functioning code but `Decimal` is practially always the better option of the two, even if it wont do `0.1 + 0.2` correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my botch using strings. It works adequately at the moment for what I need but I haven't fully tested it.

print (int_sci_notation(0.1+0.2)) will return a tupple (3,-1)

```
def int_sci_notation(decimal_value):
    #decimal value is finite value stored in double precision
    #convert to scientific string (cannot prevent E notation so force all numbers to E notation)
    tostr = format(decimal_value, ".14E")
    #get exponent from string
    if tostr[-3] == '-':
        exp = -int(tostr[-2:])
    else:
        exp = int(tostr[-2:])
    #get significant figures as an integer
    frac = tostr[1:-4].strip('0')
    sf = tostr[0]+frac[1:]
    #return the integer 'mantissa' and the exponent
    return int(sf), -int(len(sf)-1-exp)
```